# Content-based reco system in neo4j for large dataset

Tags: sql, database, neo4j, recommendation-engine, nosql

I am trying to make a recommendation website of books. I have crawled some book sites and, and have around 15 million separate books in the DB, which is in **neo4j**.

Now  for some genres, like mystery and thriller, there are about 1 million books at least. I have to make a top 20 list of recommendations. My current approach-

1. get the books
2. run a similarity comparison (vec-cosine or pearsons)
3. sort and display

are expensive and take time, not at all good for a realtime system. I thought keeping a sorted list per genre by linking neo4j to a traditional DB and getting the top ones from that db via neo4j. But that also is slow (takes a few 10s of seconds). Is there a simpler and more intuitive way to do this? Any ideas will help.

Answer (score 2):

It would be good to know what other criteria you would like to base your recommendations on, e.g. how exactly you measure similarities between books. I'm assuming it's not purely genre based.

One approach we have been taking with these dense nodes (such as your genres, or cities people live in, etc.), is to find recommendations first based on some other criteria, then boost the relevance score of the recommendation if it is connected to the correct dense node. Such a query is much more performant.

For example, when recommending 20 people you should be friends with, I'd find 100 candidates based on all other criteria and then boost the scores of candidates living in the same location as the user we're recommending for. That's 100 single-hop traversals, which will be very quick.

Have a look at [this recent webinar recording](http://watch.neo4j.org/video/118837191), you may find some inspiration in it.

Regarding similarity measures, these may need to be pre-computed, linking similar books together by `SIMILAR_TO` relationships. Such pre-computation might be done using the [Runtime](https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-framework/tree/master/runtime) of [GraphAware Framework](https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-framework), which only executes this background computation during quiet periods, thus not interfering with your regular transactional processing. Look at the [NodeRank](https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-noderank) module, which computes PageRank in Neo4j during quiet periods.